# Genetic Algorithm Travelling Salesman

Tags: genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I am trying to understand the terms genotype, phenotype and fitness in the Travelling Salesman Problem. Say I have 4 cities ABCD and their co-ordinates are (0,3)(1,4)(5,6)(2,9) what would be the genotype, phenotype and fitness of that?

Comment: It depends on coding, your graph representation, and fitness of what? You need to be more specific.

Comment: I thought they were standard terms like the order of cities visited is the phenotype I think but am not sure?

Comment: Terms are standard, the choices not. Why do you ask me what is your coding/phenotype? xD

Answer (score 1):

The *genotype* is the "genetic" information of an individual of the population that should evolve towards an optimum using a *Genetic Algorithm*.
In the case of the *Traveling Salesman Problem* (TSP), the genotype is the specific way a tour is represented in your code. A tour, e.g. could be represented as a string of city names, a list of city numbers, a list of coordinate pairs, etc.
The *phenotype* is the visible structure of an individual, as it is obtained based on the genotype. In the TSP this would be the sequence of cities as they are visited.
The *fitness* of an individual is a number that say how "good" is the individual among the population. In TSP this is related to the tour length. Since one wants to minimize the tour length, the fitness could be `1/tourLength`, or any other function of the tour length that is higher the shorter the tour is.